# In Blazor a server app, why is GetAuthenticationStateAsync() returning a different number of claims for Chrome vs MS Edge?

Tags: azure-active-directory, blazor, microsoft-edge, blazor-server-side, .net-6.0

We use Azure Active Directory for authentication to a server-side Blazor app (.net6.0). I'm attempting to authorize users to do a specific action on one of the pages. A user should be authorized if they have been added to the correct Active Directory group.

The authorization works fine in Google Chrome, but not in Edge. Same user account both times.

Here's a simplified version of what I'm doing:

```
@page "/accounting"

@layout GeneralLayout

@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthStateProvider
@inject IAuthorizationService AuthService

<PageBody>
    @if (IsVendorExpenseAccessEnabled) {
        @* show vendor expense things *@
    }
    else
    {
        @* don't show vendor expense things *@
    }
</PageBody>

@code {
    private AuthorizationResult HasFullAccessResult { get; set; }

    private bool IsVendorExpenseAccessEnabled =>
        HasFullAccessResult != null && HasFullAccessResult.Succeeded;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() {
        var authState = await AuthStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        HasFullAccessResult = await AuthService.AuthorizeAsync(authState?.User, "MY POLICY THAT CHECKS GROUP CLAIMS");
    }
}
```

When I debug this while using Chrome, `authState.User.Claims` has 14 group claims. When I debug while using Edge, `authState.User.Claims` has 12 group claims. One of those claims is the group this user needs in order to utilize page functionality.

Why are claims missing for a user when they use this page in Edge?

### Update

Seems the issue in Edge may have been a red herring. I logged out my App in Chrome then logged back in, and now these claims are missing in Chrome, too. I'm thinking it most likely has something to do with our Azure AD configuration. I overheard IT was working in there today.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that our IT department did a full sync of our On-Prem AD and Azure AD. I'm not 100% sure of the details, but something caused all of the Object IDs for the groups I was authorizing against to change. Once I realized this, I was able to update my code to authorize against these new IDs. My app's pages are now working.